# How to perform union set for multiple sets in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsset, nsmutableset

I have an array of `NSSet` instances as mentioned in below code.

```
NSArray *a = @[@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5"];
NSArray *b = @[@"1", @"2", @"3", @"6", @"7"];
NSArray *c = @[@"1", @"7", @"8", @"9", @"5"];
NSArray *d = @[@"1", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9"]; ... upto N number of arrays.
```

These all N arrays are defined in N instances of `NSSet` by using `[NSSet setWithArray:]` method to create the sets from the arrays. All N instances of sets are stored in one single Array X. Now, I need to perform union set operations for all N sets. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways of doing it. The easiest way is to iterate over the array (of sets) and simply add the new elements to a set.

```
NSMutableSet *unionSet = [NSMutableSet new];
for( NSSet *singleSet in X) // X is an array of sets as mentioned in the Q
{
  [unionSet unionSet:singleSet];
}
```

However, there is no need to create single intermediate sets before unifying it, because you can add the arrays themselves to the unionSet by using `-addObjectsFromArray:` (`NSMutableSet`), too.

As a hint I want to mention that in your example (which might differ from the real word), having simply numbers it might by the easier way to use `NSIndexSet` and `NSMutableIndexSet` from the very beginning.